# Using SciPy to Fit a Levy-Stable Distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

In 1.2 SciPy added the [ability to fit a Levy-Stable distribution](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/7374).  I have a few distributions I'd like to fit but I'm having some issues getting the fit to run.

Here is my test case:

```
points = 1000
jennys_constant = 8675309
alpha, beta = 1.8, -0.5

draw = levy_stable.rvs(alpha, beta, size=points, random_state=jennys_constant)
print(levy_stable.fit(draw))
```

I felt that if I drew from a Levy-Stable distribution that I should be able to fit that draw fairly easily.  However, I'm getting a lot of warnings like the below and the problem is taking a very long time on 1000 points.

```
C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_continuous_distns.py:3857: IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent.
intg = integrate.quad(f, -xi, np.pi/2, **intg_kwargs)[0]
```

Have I set up the problem incorrectly?  The [SciPy Docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.levy_stable.html#scipy.stats.levy_stable) are a bit thin on the subject.

I'm having similar issues fitting my real world data.

Comment: Perhaps is the value that you're using for jennys constant, [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JennysConstant.html) looks like you missed a decimal point. Hope it helps

Comment: @TavoGLC, using Jenny's Constant for random_state seems humor.  But maybe so was your comment.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have set up your problem correctly; the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html)  for `rv_continuous`, the superclass of `levy_stable`, has links for all its functions (e.g., [`fit()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html)).  My hunch is the really slow runtime is a SciPy bug.

Using [pylevy](https://github.com/josemiotto/pylevy)'s [`fit_levy()`](https://pylevy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/levy.html#levy.fit_levy) seems to work:

```
import scipy.stats as st, levy

points = 1000
jennys_constant = 8675309
alpha, beta = 1.8, -0.5

draw = st.levy_stable.rvs(alpha, beta, size=points, random_state=jennys_constant)
print(levy.fit_levy(draw))
```

The result seems reasonably good (and `fit_levy()` is quite fast):

```
(par=0, alpha=1.84, beta=-0.29, mu=0.11, sigma=1.00, 1863.61502664704)
```

Comment: Interesting, is pylevy in conda?

Comment: My hunch is it is not; I do not use conda.  I followed the install instructions on pylevy's GitHub page that is linked in my answer.  The page has [version 1.0](https://github.com/josemiotto/pylevy/commit/ed27245c30f5d1d18272860ba62439b5294fbef1), while the version on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PyLevy) is quite old (0.3).

Answer (score 6):

Scipy's implementation of levy stable distribution primarily uses Nolan's method that splits the parameter space (alpha, beta) into several segments some of which require tricky integrals to be evaluated.

Scipy estimates parameters using MLE and this can be very slow due to these same integrals. There is experimental FFT support for evaluating levy stable PDFs, this feature hopefully improves significantly with [this PR](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/9523/) pencilled in with a 1.3 milestone. However, it seems the fit() method is still quite slow even when using FFT.

There is a faster quantile estimator (McCulloch) that is used as a first guess for a distributions parameters (when estimating using fit()). This can be called directly using _fitstart().

That said, it seems the parameterization used to generate Scipy's random samples (from rvs()) is different to the one use to generate pdfs/cdfs. Something I hope to look at in the future.

Until then (as suggested by @Ulrich in their answer) you can either use pylevy or alternatively use _fitstart() to estimate the parameters and convert the parameterization afterwards.

```py
from scipy.stats import levy_stable
import numpy as np

points = 1000000
jennys_constant = 8675309
alpha, beta = 1.8, -0.5

draw = levy_stable.rvs(alpha, beta, size=points, random_state=jennys_constant)

# use scipy's quantile estimator to estimate the parameters and convert to S parameterization
pconv = lambda alpha, beta, mu, sigma: (alpha, beta, mu - sigma * beta * np.tan(np.pi * alpha / 2.0), sigma)
pconv(*levy_stable._fitstart(draw))

>>> (1.7990380668349146, -0.5661063359664303,
      -0.012873575589969821, 0.998276003705684)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, all the other distributions fit fairly fast, but levy_stable is taking hours.

Comment: @NoName I think the slowness is an artifact of scipy's MLE method for fitting distributions. There are some optimizations and fixes that are waiting in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/9523 but no one really able (or has the time) to review the PR.